# C#: splitting a string and not returning empty string

Tags: c#, split

I have a string:

```
a = "1;2;3;"
```

And I would like to `split` it this way:

```
foreach (string b in a.split(';'))
```

How can I make sure that I return only `1`, `2`, `3` and not an 'empty string'?

If I split `1;2;3` then I will get what I want. But if I split `1;2;3;` then I get an extra 'empty string'. I have taken suggestions and done this:

```
string[] batchstring = batch_idTextBox.Text.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

However, I am getting these errors:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params
>   char[])' has some invalid arguments   C:\Documents and
>   Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs    18  36  EnterData
>
> Error 2   Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.StringSplitOptions'
>   to 'char' C:\Documents and Settings\agordon\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\lomdb\EnterData\DataEntry\DAL.cs    18  68  EnterData

Answer (score 68, accepted):

String.Split takes an **array** when including any `StringSplitOptions`:

```
string[] batchstring = batch_idTextBox.Text.Split(new [] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If you don't need options, the syntax becomes easier:

```
string[] batchstring = batch_idTextBox.Text.Split(';');
```

Answer (score 22):

Use [`StringSplitOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions.aspx).

```
a.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 6):

Pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` to the Split method.

**EDIT**

The Split method does not have an overload to split by a single character. You need to specify an array of characters.

```
foo.Split(new char[] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 2):

Didn't know about split options. If you didn't have that you could...

```
a.Split(';').Where(s => s.Length > 0).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
string test = "1;2;3;";
test = String.Join(",", test.TrimEnd((char)59).Split((char)59));

string test = "1;2;3;";
test = String.Join(",", test.TrimEnd(';').Split(';'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
a.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

There are 4 overloads of `.Split`, two of them don't support `StringSplitOptions` and use the `params` format (so you don't need to create an array of splitters), two of them support `StringSplitOptions` and require an array of `char` or `string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string line="Hello! Have nice day."
string[] substr = line.Split(new[] {' '}, 2);
```

Above code will split the line into two substrings based on first space.
substr[0] will have "Hello!"
substr[1] will have "Have nice day.". Here 2 in Split is an integer counter, you can pass any value based on your requirement.