# Regex for slitting string by pipe skips empty strings

Tags: c#, regex

This is my regex:

```
var separator = '|';
Regex csvSplit = new Regex("(?:^|" + separator + ")(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"|[^" + separator + "]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
var test = csvSplit.Matches("10734|Vls, p|6||1.5");
```

As you can see, there is one empty record.

This is what I get:
[image]

I was expecting empty string on index 3, but instead it is skipped. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you do it right from the start [using the CSV parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542996/how-to-split-csv-whose-columns-may-contain/6543418#6543418)?

Comment: `.Split(new [] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` Is regex mandatory ? or the basic [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) is engouth

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393119/c-splitting-a-string-and-not-returning-empty-string

Comment: @DragandDrop It is mandatory, I don't want a completely new solution, I just want to modify the regex.

Comment: Ok, then why don't you escape the separator in the first place? `|` is a special char, an alternation operator. Your pattern looks like `(?:^||)("(?:[^"]+|"")*"|[^|]+)` and `(?:^||)` is really fishy, did you mean `(?:^|\|)`?

Comment: Can you have a string like `|10734||1.5|"aa""bb"aa` (5 items in the output expected)? Or only strings like `|10734||1.5|"aa""bb"` are expected?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can have both.

Comment: @Good, then I know what regex will work for you. But there is another answer posted, I will wait till they come up with their proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex instead:

```
(?:^|(?<=\|))((?:"[^"]*"|[^|])*)(?=\||$)
```

Comment: Your pattern ignores the fact that `|` inside a verbatim string literal should not be split upon. See `(\"(?:[^\"]+|\"\")*\"` in the original regex. Thus, it won't work with `|10734||1.5|"aa""bb|cc"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Good point. I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: No, it does not work, try against [`|10734||1.5|"aa|""b|b"|"aa""bb|"aa|`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5e%7c%5c%7c%29%28%28%3f%3a%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%7c%5b%5e%7c%5d%29*%29%28%3f%3d%5c%7c%7c%24%29&i=%7c10734%7c%7c1.5%7c%22aa%7c%22%22b%7cb%22%7c%22aa%22%22bb%7c%22aa%7c)

Comment: But [it still missed to match the empty string at the start](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5c%7c%7c%5e%29%28%28%3f%3a%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22%7c%5b%5e%7c%5d%29*%29%28%3f%3d%5c%7c%7c%24%29&i=%7c10734%7c%7c1.5%7c%22aa%7c%22%22b%7cb%22%7c%22aa%22%22bb%7c%22aa%7c).

Comment: Indeed. Fixed now. Thanks.